# Multilingual bibliographies with biblatex-chicago babel hyphenation

Tags: biblatex, languages, biber

Don't know what I did (if I did anything) but seems multilingual libraries don't work for me anymore... I have some german and english references in an english document and so I want that english references are all output in small letters - for german titles, however, I want to keep the original spelling, including all capitals. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[british,german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setquotestyle{british}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage{authblk}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000


% ********************************BIBLATEX**************************
\usepackage[language=british,isbn=false,authordate,doi=false,babel=other]{biblatex-chicago}

\defbibheading{quell}{\section{Primary Ressources}}
\defbibheading{lit}{\section{References}}
% ******************************************************************
```

references would be, for example:

```
@book{aunger_darwinizing_2001,
title = {Darwinizing Culture: The Status of Memetics as a Science},
isbn = {0192632442},
language = {english},
hyphenation = {english},
pagetotal = {256},
publisher = {Oxford University Press},
editor = {Aunger, Robert},
date = {2001-01-04},
}

@book{rautenberg_einfuhrung_2008,
location = {Wiesbaden},
title = {Einführung in die mathematische Logik: ein Lehrbuch},
isbn = {9783834805782 3834805785},
shorttitle = {Einführung in die mathematische Logik},
hyphenation = {german},
publisher = {Vieweg + Teubner},
author = {Rautenberg, Wolfgang},
date = {2008},
}
```

but what happens is that all are

Comment: The `language=british` option setting prints the bibliography under one language module - `british`. To obtain a multilingual bibliography, remove this setting and leave `babel=other` as-is. If the main document language is English, you should load babel with `british` last: `\usepackage[german,british]{babel}`.

Comment: I tried this but it still gives me:

Aunger, Robert, ed. 2001. Darwinizing Culture: The Status of Memetics as a Science. Oxford University Press.
Although it should be:
Aunger, Robert, ed. 2001. Darwinizing culture: The status of memetics as a science. Oxford University Press.

The problem are not the German entries as one would expect... how is this even possible? It seems the bibliography is printed receiving completely all format features from the bib file...

Comment: I found in the biblatex manual that 
`By default, converting to sentence case is enabled for the following language identifiers: american, british, canadian, english, australian, newzealand as well as the aliases USenglish and UKenglish. Use \DeclareCaseLangs to extend or change this list.`
but that's simply not true since even when I leave out the babel option and do not use any other options than ecessary it gives me no sentence cased titles... I would be very grateful for help, really I have no idea...

Comment: Refer to the biblatex-chicago manual on title casing. The 0.9.9b release notes state that you should use the `authordate-trad` style to obtain sentence-style capitalization in titles.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! you saved my day! Just wasn't carful enough... Cheers!

Comment: No problem. I'll post an answer to take this post off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2):

The *Chicago Manual of Style* no longer imposes sentence-style capitalization on titles. In response to this change the `biblatex-chicago` author moved sentence case title formatting from the default `authordate` style to a new style call `authordate-trad`. So to obtain an English bibliography with sentence-cased titles load `babel` and `biblatex` with the option settings:

```
\usepackage[german,british]{babel}
\usepackage[authordate-trad,babel=hyphen]{biblatex-chicago}
```

For a multilingual bibliography incorporating both English and German strings, change the setting `babel=hyphen` to `babel=other`. Note that you might need to protect some words in titles from down-casing. For example:

```
title = {Darwinizing Culture: {The} Status of Memetics as a Science},
```

Alternatively you can use the `subtitle` field:

```
title = {Darwinizing Culture},
subtitle = {The Status of Memetics as a Science},
```

Also note that sentence case is applied only under the language modules specified in `\DeclareCaseLangs`. By default:

```
\DeclareCaseLangs{%
  american,british,canadian,english,australian,newzealand,
  USenglish,UKenglish}
```

To include `german` in this list, add the following to your preamble:

```
\DeclareCaseLangs*{german}
```